# Can't access database from views using MongoDB NodeJS Express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm having trouble accessing my database from one of the two views I created for my app. I created the app using Node.JS, Express and MongoDB for the data store. The data is stored in a collection called entries with a key-value pairing (date: 'date', link: 'string'). In my database view I can access and loop through the JSON object 'entries' after but I can't seem to do the same from my index view despite the fact that I wrote a test to console.log(entries) and when I open both pages separately it prints a result.

When I run the code I get this error: Error cannot read property of undefined

I wonder if I am missing something in how I am referencing them in my code.

Below is my app.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var moment = require('moment');
//database stuff
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//connect to the data store and the set up the database
var db = mongoose.connection;

//connect to the database
var conn = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Mandela_Diaries/data');

//Create a model which connects to the schema and entries collection in the Mandela_Diaries database
var Entry = mongoose.model("Entry", new Schema({date: 'date', link: 'string'}), "entries");

mongoose.connection.on("open", function() {
  console.log("mongodb is connected!");
});

var routes = require('./models/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var database = require('./routes/database');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var templatemain = require('./routes/template-main');

var app = express();

// Methodoverride at the top
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//serving static files
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));

app.use('/', routes);

app.use('/', routes);

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/database', database);
app.use('/create', database);
app.use('/delete', database);
app.use('/:id', database);
// app.use('/database/#{entry._id}?/delete', database);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
module.exports.Entry = Entry;

app.listen(8080);

console.log("The server has started");
```

My database.js code is so:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Entry = mongoose.model('Entry');

//The route for getting data for the database - GET form
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  //Send the current entries to the page
  Entry.find({}, function(err, entries) {
    console.log(entries);
    if(err) {
      res.status(404).json({"error": "not found", "err":err});
      return;
    } else {
      res.render('database', {title: 'database', entries: entries});
      //console.log(entries);
      //entries.forEach(printjson);
    }
  });

});

//The route for posting data to the database - POST
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var newEntry = new Entry(req.body);
  newEntry.save(function(err, entries){
    if (err !== null) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    } else {
      res.redirect('database');
    };
  });
});

//The route for deleting data to the database - Delete/remove todo item by its id
// Changed path from `/` to `/:id`
    router.delete('/:id', function (req, res) {
        Entry.findById(req.params.id)
            .exec(function(err, entries) {
               // changed `if (err || !doc)` to `if (err || !entries)`
                if (err || !entries) {
                    res.statusCode = 404;
                    res.send({});
                } else {
                    entries.remove(function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            res.statusCode = 403;
                            res.send(err);
                        } else {
                            res.send('Deleted entry with link: ', entries.link);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    });

module.exports = router;
```

My index.js code is below:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Entry = mongoose.model('Entry');
app.locals.moment = require('moment');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('/', { title: 'Express' });
  Entry.find({}, function(err, entries) {
        if(err) {
            res.status(404).json({"error": "not found", "err":err});
            return;
        } else {
            res.render('/', {title: 'database',  entries: entries});
        }
    });
});

console.log("new code works");

module.exports = router;
```

My script.js code where I want to loop through the object and add the elements to the DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Date picker jQuery
    $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $( "#format" ).change(function() {
          $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
        });
      });

    var browserDate = new Date();
    var videoDate = new Date(1962);
    //var month = browserDate.getMonth() + 1;
    //var day = browserDate.getDate();
    var year = browserDate.getFullYear();

    $.getJSON('/', function() {
        console.log(entries);
        $.each(entries, function(i) {
            $("#context").append("ON THIS DAY " + context + " YEARS AGO: ");
        });
    });

    var context = year - videoDate;

    //$('#context').append("ON THIS DAY " + context + " YEARS AGO:");
    $('#context').html = "ON THIS DAY " + context + " YEARS AGO: ";
    console.log("ON THIS DAY " + context + " YEARS AGO: ");

    //$("body").append("Hey there!");

    console.log("This worked!!");
    console.log(browserDate);
});
```

Then the database.jade file where I can access the entries JSON object somehow:

```
extends layout

block content
    .container
      .row
        .col-md-12
          h1 The Mandela Diaries Database
      .row
        .col-md-4
          h3 Add Entry
      .row
        .col-md-12
          form.form-inline(method='post', action='/create')
            .form-group
              label(for='date') Date: 
              input#datepicker.form-control.datepicker(type='text', name='date')
            .form-group
              label(for='link') Link: 
              input#link.form-control(type='string', name='link')
            button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Submit
      .row
        p
              | Format options:
              br
              select#format
                option(value='mm/dd/yy') Default - mm/dd/yy
                option(value='yy-mm-dd') ISO 8601 - yy-mm-dd
                option(value='d M, y') Short - d M, y
                option(value='d MM, y') Medium - d MM, y
                option(value='DD, d MM, yy') Full - DD, d MM, yy
                option(value="'day' d 'of' MM 'in the year' yy") With text - 'day' d 'of' MM 'in the year' yy
      br
      ul#dbentries.col-md-12
        each entry in entries
          p= 'Date: ' + entry.date + ': Link: ' + entry.link + ' '
            span
              //- the problem was a missing `?` the `_method` parameter is in the query string
              //- `method-override` middleware will check for this
              form(method='POST', action='/database/#{entry._id}?_method=DELETE')
                button(type='submit') Delete
```

And the index.jade file where I can't access the JSON object even when I try the same code as the other I still get the error: Error cannot read property of undefined.

```
extends layout

block content
   #widget.container
      .row
        #header.col-xs-12.header
          img#Mandela_Logo(src='/public/images/Logo_MandelaDiaries.png')
      .row
         //#context.col-xs-12
         //   each entry in entries
         //       p= 'ON THIS DAY ' + moment(entry.date).fromNow() + ' -  Link: ' + entry.link + ' '
      .row
        #videos.col-xs-12
          .embed-responsive.embed-responsive-4by3
            iframe(width='300', height='169', src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/4HqtAMHrJ8s', frameborder='0', allowfullscreen='')
      .row
        #footer.col-xs-12
          img#NMF_logo(src='/public/images/Logo_NMF.png')
          img#SABC_logo(src='/public/images/Logo_SABCNews.png')
```

I think it may be a simple fix but that's just me. Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.js, you are calling **[`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render)** method twice. The first time you call it renders the view and sends the rendered HTML string to the client. Try to remove the first call and use the one in the **`find()`** callback:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    /* res.render('/', { title: 'Express' }); <--- this is where your issue is */
    Entry.find({}, function(err, entries) {
        if(err) {
            res.status(404).json({"error": "not found", "err":err});
            return;
        } else {
            res.render('/', {title: 'database',  entries: entries});
        }
    });
});
```